# Missing font tags on default ckeditor config

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, tags, ckeditor

I'm having a super annoying problem with CKEditor.

When I first load it, it appears like this:

[image: Initial config]

then, when I click inside to type, it goes like this:

[image: font style and size]

ok, everything just fine, but look what happens with the content when I type something:

[image: where are the tags?]

I don't have any Arial 12 labeling, so when I get this HTML and process it, I'll never know it should be Arial 12.

Now, if I manually change it, then it works, but when I click outside the CKEditor window and then back inside again, it returns to the initial state, with no tags, look:

[image: Crazy CKEditor]

I've tried every solution on google, like adding

`font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS" !important;
 font-size: 12px !important;` in `content.css`,

or adding

```
config.font_defaultLabel = 'Arial';
config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '12px';
```

in config.js, etc.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: The images are hard to read, but if you right click and then open in a new tab, it opens readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what `config.font_defaultLabel`, `config.fontSize_defaultLabel` do. They do only one thing - set the default labels in the dropdowns. Nothing more.

So how do you apply Arial 12px to the whole content? Using `contents.css` just like you did.

> I don't have any Arial 12 labeling, so when I get this HTML and process it, I'll never know it should be Arial 12.

You just set it in the `contents.css` so I think you know that very well ;).

> But I want `<span>` tags wrapping the whole content! (my quote :P)

CKEditor will not help with that, because this is against good practices. You should use power of CSS instead of dirtying your HTML with presentation markup.